# URL status connection 404 usando jSoup

Tags: java, jsoup

Estoy usando jSoup para obtener distinta información, entre otros enlaces, de la que posteriormente saco información. Para ello uso un método que me da el código de la conexión:

```
    public static int getStatusConnectionCode(String url) {
    int statusCode = 0; //o algún otro resultado que indique que es error
    try {
        Response response = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").timeout(100000).ignoreHttpErrors(true).execute();
        statusCode = response.statusCode();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //procura mejorar la forma en que tratas tus excepciones
        System.out.println("Excepción al obtener el Status Code: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return statusCode;
}
```

Sin embargo me encuentro con que en más de una ocasión el código me da 404, es decir que no encuentra la página, cuando si copio y pego la URL entro perfectamente. ¿Hay alguna forma de pulir el código y que no me ocurran estas cosas? Además ocurre de forma aleatoria, y no es problema de conexión de internet ni problema de la página, puesto que de vez en cuando veo en la propia ejecución del programa estos casos y pruebo si realmente no existe la página.

Comment: La forma de "pulir" es precisamente obteniendo el statuscode de la conexión, statusCode = response.statusCode(); por lo que comentas quieres revisar antes de hacer la petición??? considera revisar porque obtienes 404 al no encontrarse la url activa.

Comment: @Elenasys Sí, pero algo tiene que haber mal cuando por ejemplo ésta página me da código 404 cuando manualmente entro perfectamente, y la URL está bien escrita (es copia y pega): https://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Paquete-trilog%C3%ADa-Fable/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d8024d530aa2?DownloadType=Game#LiveZone